# How to go to last row of result set in JDBC with ctree server

Tags: java, jdbc, ctree

May I know that anyone have idea on how to go to last row of the result set in JDBC with ctree server?

We have try to use the rs.last() but it return the message said that "Driver not support this function".

Is anyone know in c-tree server, what is the function to have the same result as rs.last() in SQL server?

Comment: If immediately jumping to the last row isn't supported you might need to iterate through the results to get the last. Or you could try to reorder the result to make the last record the first. :)

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also, have you checked the documentation, to see if the driver actually supports TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE or TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE?  `ResultSet.last()` is only supported when you requested those types of result set (the default is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) **and** the driver actually supports those types. The error message suggests that either you did not ask for a scrollable result set, or the driver doesn't support it at all.